# Animated line drawing (SVG) with CSS

Tags: svg, css-animations

I have a SVG which I animate with CSS using `stroke-dashoffset` and `stroke-dasharray` depending on the scroll position. This works fine.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xVRXrY

What I’d like to achieve is that when the animation is complete (or e.g. when I scrolled down 500px) the stroke shall deconstruct itself from the beginning with the same animation like in my sketch here.

[image: See this sketch for a better understanding]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should use `getTotalLength()` to get the current path length.
Then, this script is an example where the line grows until the middle of the scroll, then it disappears like in your drawings.

Here is a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Ltbvyepj/

And here is the Javascript code:

```
var path = document.querySelector(".path");
// Get the actual length of your path.
var len = path.getTotalLength();
// Dashes have the exact length of the path.
path.style.strokeDasharray = len + " " + len;
// Shift of the length of the path, so the line is quite not visible.
path.style.strokeDashoffset = len;
// Attach to the window's scroll event.
window.addEventListener( 'scroll', function() {
    // Getting the page dimensions.
    var rect = document.querySelector( 'html' ).getBoundingClientRect();
    // Height is the size of the page which is out of screen.
    var height = rect.height - window.innerHeight;
    // Percent of scroll bar. 0 Means the top, 1 the bottom.
    var percent = height < 0 ? 1
            : -rect.top / height;
    // If you omit the `2 *` you will get a growing only path.
    path.style.strokeDashoffset = len * (1 - 2 * percent);
}, false);
```